# creating custom functions in display template

Tags: javascript, display-template

```
            <a title="_#= $htmlEncode(Srch.Res.sb_GoSearch) =#_" class="ms-srch-sb-searchLink" id="_#= $htmlEncode(searchBoxLinkId) =#_" 
                onclick="CustomFunction();" href="javascript: {}">
                <img src="_#= $urlHtmlEncode(imagesUrl) =#_" class="ms-srch-sbLarge-searchImg" id="searchImg" alt="_#= $htmlEncode(Srch.Res.sb_GoSearch) =#_" />
            </a>
```

I have this bit of code in a searchbox display template. What my function does is redirect the page on click. However when I run the code above it says that the function is undefined. 
There is nothing wrong with the code as I have tested it.

```
<!--#_      function CustomFunction()       {
        // get query string value

        // get value of input search box
        var searchb = 'test';
        // create link
        var searchlink= window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname+'/Dave2/Pages/FAQSearch.aspx?category='+category+'&k='+searchb;
        // redirect to search page
        window.location = searchlink;
    }
_#-->
```

The function is placed above the html and it is all in the html display template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a scoping issue, that your function is only being defined inside the scope of the display template rendering. Try this:

```
 <a title="_#= $htmlEncode(Srch.Res.sb_GoSearch) =#_" class="ms-srch-sb-searchLink" id="_#= $htmlEncode(searchBoxLinkId) =#_" 
            onclick="window.CustomFunction();" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <img src="_#= $urlHtmlEncode(imagesUrl) =#_" class="ms-srch-sbLarge-searchImg" id="searchImg" alt="_#= $htmlEncode(Srch.Res.sb_GoSearch) =#_" />
        </a>

<!--#_      window.CustomFunction = function(){
    // get query string value

    // get value of input search box
    var searchb = 'test';
    // create link
    var searchlink= window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname+'/Dave2/Pages/FAQSearch.aspx?category='+category+'&k='+searchb;
    // redirect to search page
    window.location = searchlink;
}
_#-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your javascript functions in the below area so that it can be called onClick.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="forms.css" runat="server"/>
</ContentTemplate></SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Assets/jquery-ui.css"></link>
<script src="../../Assets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Assets/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: He is trying to run it on click of a link `onclick="CustomFunction();" href="javascript: {}">` and not on load

Comment: oh sorry let me revise my answer